# Update Memcache Result When Database Updated

Tags: php, memcached

All listing pages on my web application comes from memcache with TTL 1 hour. We update particular memcache key when any new post comes. By default new post will come to page one so with every new post we update memcache key for page 1.

```
$data = $cache->getCache()->get($key);
array_unshift($data, $newcontent);
$cache->getCache()->set($key, $data);
```

Which works fine but some times it comes with Fatal Error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4 bytes)  in on line 35 Cache.php

On line 35 we have cache set function written.

Current memory_limit is 128 M , which I feel sufficient and application running from  last 2 years with no memory problem. Raising memory limit to 256 M causes slow response from server when multiple threads are running.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated in terms of fix/performance.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that your memory limit is set to 32M. What does `php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini -i | grep memory_limit` shows?

Comment: or if you can't access command line add phpinfo to a php file `<?php phpinfo();` and look for the local value for `memory_limit` (don't do this on a live server, or if you have to make sure it's on a non-public facing file and locked down by IP & auth)

Comment: Hi Thanks for response , i check my memory limit in php.ini is 128 M as mentioned above.